# Would this be correct grammar: "(place) is a must-do for anybody who considers themselves a vacationer."

Tags: expressions

I'm really asking about the must-do in the middle.

Comment: Yes, this is a great sentence!

Comment: What attempts have you made to see if it is used (Ngrams, a Google search ...)?

Comment: 'Must-do' is given in various dictionaries, but the sense of 'do' involved here ('do' Venice etc) is highly informal to slang. [[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/do)]: **do** 24. (tr) informal: to visit or explore as a sightseer or tourist: _to do Westminster Abbey_. I'd say the caveat also applies to your sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The OED does not list "must-do", though it does list "must-see".

But GloWBe (the corpus of Global Web-based English) has 553 instances of "must-do" (92 in UK sources, and over 50 in each of US, AUS, NZ) as against 1883 instances of "must-see".

So, though it hasn't yet got into the OED, and is less common than "must-see", it is clearly a word in use around the Anglosphere.

Comment: But OP's usage is far narrower.

Comment: Also, your data doesn't specifically address OP's nounal usage.